# iOS Valid signing identity not found

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

I see this questions comes up a lot, but no answers for me.  I have revoked the previous Development and Distribution Certificates and generated new ones.  I have downloaded both certificates and installed them by double-clicking.  In my Keychain Access I can see my certificates and they have a green circle with a check mark saying "This certificate is valid".

Then I created my new Development and Distribution Provisioning Profiles and downloaded them.  They have a green button showing they are Active.  I drag the downloaded Provisioning Profiles over to my Xcode icon.  I open Xcode Organizer and click on LIBRARY --> Provisioning Profiles.  They are there with today's date on them but the status is "Valid signing identity not found"

What's the missing step here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got some help from someone who understands the Keychain Access tool.  The problem was that I had multiple certifications and XCode was getting confused.

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to set Code Signing Identity under Build Settings !

[image]

You have to set all to the same code signing .

And you have to do it in your Project, and Targets too !

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you're still using XCode 4.X you could try Organizer->Library(top left)->Refresh(bottom right) and see if that solves the problem for you.

Hope this helps!